# Difference between Set-Variable foo -Scope Global -Value "bar" and $global:foo = "bar"

Tags: powershell

What is the difference between
    Set-Variable foo -Scope Global -Value "bar"
and
    $global:foo = "bar"

I have seen that Set-Variable implements -WhatIf/-Confim so the assignment only happens if these are not set or the action is confirmed whereas the assignment happens regardless.  Is there anything else lurking?

---

**UPDATE**

Following is an example of how the 2 are different in the presence of -Whatif / -Confirm:

```
Clear-Variable foo -ErrorAction:SilentlyContinue # just in case
Function repro {
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)] Param()
    Set-Variable foo -Scope Global -Value "bar"
}
repro -WhatIf
Write-Host "`$global:foo=$($global:foo)"
```

You should see:

```
What if: Performing the operation "Set variable" on target "Name: foo Value: bar".
$global:foo=
```

However:

```
Clear-Variable foo -ErrorAction:SilentlyContinue # just in case
Function repro {
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)] Param()
    $global:foo = "bar"
}
repro -WhatIf
Write-Host "`$global:foo=$($global:foo)"
```

Now you get:

```
$global:foo=bar
```

Comment: "...so the assignment only happens if these are not set" - what gave you that impression? The two commands are equivalent. (Try them yourself in a new PowerShell window.) I guess I'm wondering what's provoking the question?

Comment: @Bill_Stewart, Using `-WhatIf` or denying a `-Confirm` don't actually set the variable. Both expressions produce the same output but they are definitely not equivalent.

Comment: Without the other parameters, the two commands do, indeed, do the same thing. `-WhatIf` and `-Confirm` are cmdlet "plumbing" common to other cmdlets.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart.  I have updated the original question with case where the 2 differ.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart, as stated, they produce the same result in **this** scenario but to say the assignment operator `=` is functionally equivalent to `Set-Variable` is `$false`. See my answer for an explanation.

Comment: (?) I didn't claim that the `=` operator and `Set-Variable` are equivalent. I said the effect (of what was asked initially) was equivalent. (Same as what you said in one of the comments to your answer, incidentally.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference isn't much but the `Set-Variable` has a few more options available to it than just a regular assignment expression. It's just a matter of how verbose you want to be with your syntax and what you are trying to accomplish.

### Assignment Expressions

These are simple, quick variable assignments not much to it.

```
$foo = "bar"
# If you want to change scope, add it
$global:foo = "bar"
$script:foo = "bar"
```

### `Set-Variable` CmdLet

As you've pointed out, the `Set-Variable` Cmdlet has a few more options with it, like `-WhatIf` and `-Confirm`. It also has a few other options like setting the type of variable with `-Option` and `-PassThru`. `-Option` allows for the setting of constants, readonly variables, or private scoped variables. `-PassThru` is pretty useful to and I'll give an example below. A couple more parameters are also available to so review them [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/set-variable)

#### Why PassThru is cool

```
# PassThru executes your Set-Variable and then continues to
# pass the variable through the pipeline so with it you can 
# assign your variable and then immediately start working with it
Set-Variable -Name "FooArr" -Value @("bar", "baz", "boom") -PassThru | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Value
}
$FooArr # Still assigned
bar
baz
boom
```

#### Working with Constants

```
# Constant
Set-Variable -Name "ImAConstant" -Value "Try to delete me" -Option Constant
Remove-Variable -Name "ImAConstant"
# Error
Remove-Variable : Cannot remove variable ImAConstant because it is constant or 
read-only. If the variable is read-only, try the operation again specifying the Force 
option.
At line:2 char:1
+ Remove-Variable -Name "ImAConstant"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (ImAConstant:String) [Remove-Variable], Ses 
   sionStateUnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : VariableNotRemovable,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Remo 
   veVariableCommand
```

#### Working with Read only

```
Set-Variable -Name "ImReadOnly" -Value "Delete me" -Option ReadOnly
Remove-Variable -Name "ImReadOnly" -Force # Removed
```

These are just a few examples. Pretty cool stuff.

#### Update to OP Update

In your function `repro`, you use `SupportsShouldProcess` in your `CmdLetBinding()` but you still need to block it up for your assignment with some code for it to run the way you are thinking.

```
Function repro {
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)] Param()
    if ($pscmdlet.ShouldProcess('$global:foo', "Sets Variable")){
        $global:foo = "bar"
    }
}
```

This will produce the same result as your original `Set-Variable` call with `-WhatIf`.

Comment: So I gather that $global:foo = "bar" is exactly equivalent to Set-Variable foo -Value "bar" (with no other parameters).

Comment: `Set-Variable -Name foo -value "bar" -Scope Global` is functionally equivalent to `$global:foo = "bar"`

Comment: @DaveMontgomery Check my update to correspond to your update